# Find a value from one worksheet in a designated range in another

Tags: vba, excel

**Intent**

1. It will consist of 11 identical Worksheets (10 for data entry specific areas of the site being worked on, and 1 "Master" which gathers the totals)
2. The Master Worksheet is where the Start Date is changed. When the Start Date is changed it is reflected in the 10 data entry Worksheets. There are numeric values as well showing how far away the Start Date is.
3. When the Start Date is changed, the values need to move with the Start Date (i.e. if the Start Date is January 5 and there is already data on the data entry worksheets, if the Start Date is changed to January 7 then all data on all worksheets will need to move to the right by 2)

**Intended Process**

I was able to get the first two functions working, however it's the last one that's causing some grief.

What I had in mind was a procedural copy-paste of sorts. When the Start Date is changed it would go to the first data entry worksheet and copy the current header settings to a "Transfer" Worksheet, preserving the original date settings for that worksheet. It would then delete the data in the data entry worklist.

The next step was to go to the first of the data entry Worksheets (Codenames in the background start with "Sz"), match the first numeric value of the data entry to the Transfer worksheet, retrieve the data and paste the column data into it's new location.

When it's all done with the data entry worksheet it would then clear out the "Transfer" worksheet, move to the next data entry worksheet, and repeat the process.

**Problem**

Unfortunately, the code I have written is saying it is finding the numeric values, when that numeric value doesn't exist. And then it sometimes has an error message stating "Code execution has been interrupted".

I have been working on this for about fifteen hours overtime, in addition to about a full week. I have googled countless potential solutions, and tried many workarounds, but am officially at a dead end. I have mostly taught myself through other people's examples, so I'm not an expert in Excel VBA.

If I can get the matching functions working correctly, I believe I should be able to handle the rest, but suggestions on more efficient methods are more than welcome.

I don't use Forums much, but I'll try to paste the code below.

Please let me know what other information I could provide.

*Edit*: Here is the sample of the Workbook. To run the function you will need to be on the "Plant" worksheet (Sz001): [Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t5beh6h1wh2pctz/Example.xlsm?dl=0)

Code:

```
Sub Test()
Dim sh As Worksheet, flg As Boolean

For Each sh In Worksheets

'FUNCTIONAL: If sh.CodeName Like "Sz0*" Then 'flg = True

If sh.CodeName = "Sz001" Then 'Isolating a single Worksheet for testing

'Copy original values and location to Transfer Worksheet
'DISABLED THIS SECTION WHILE TESTING
'sh.Select
'ActiveSheet.Range("H8:ABI460").Copy
'Worksheets("Transfer").Select
'ActiveSheet.Range("H8").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Begin Matching Loop -THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUES ARE HAPPENING
Dim xlRange As Range 'Current sh Range
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet 'Current sh Worksheet
Dim xlCell As Range 'Cell function is currently looking at
Dim x As Range

Set xlSheet = sh
Set xlRange = xlSheet.Range("H6:ABI6")

For Each xlCell In xlRange

    Set x = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(what:=xlCell, after:=Worksheets("Transfer").Range("G6"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

    If Not x Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox Cells(xlCell.Row, xlCell.Column) & "Found"
    Else
        MsgBox Cells(xlCell.Row, xlCell.Column) & "Not Found"
    End If

Next xlCell

End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you provide the before and after samples of small test data sets?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for responding! I just updated the post to include the example file. The original workbook that I'm rebuilding didn't have this functionality before; the before workbook kept the "Start Date" notification at a static location (Always column ND:NE) and the dates at the top shifted around to 6 months ahead and behind, so the data never moved. This would be new functionality for the Workbook. If you think the original (before) workbook could help I'll modify one and upload it for you.

Comment: @bh201 I've looked at your file, the code starts at looking for H6 and it finds it - in H6. Rather than search the entire sheet for matches, perhaps you want to search from row 8 down?

Comment: I've looked at the file as well, and I'm not clear about this _go to the first of the data entry Worksheets (Codenames in the background start with "Sz"),_ **match the first numeric value of the data entry to the Transfer worksheet**. What range are you trying to search (what is "ActiveSheet.Cells"?). There is a conflict between "ActiveSheet" and Worksheets("Transfer") - it looks like you want to find the value in Transfer, row 6, but if ActiveSheet is something else it won't work: the "After" parameter needs to be in the same range as Find

Comment: You're on the right track where it needs to find the value in Row 6 of the "Transfer worksheet". I removed the Activesheet from the find function and it seems to resolve the "Code execution...interruption", thank you. However, it's still saying it's finding the value from the "Plant" (Sz001) worksheet in "Transfer" Row 6 when the value doesn't exist (148.1, 148.2). I was wondering, is there a way to restrict the Find function to just Row 6 of "Transfer", or is the Find function the incorrect one to use? Thank you for the help so far guys - it is much appreciated!

Comment: I think I figured out what you were trying to do: search each value from row 6 on sheet Sz001, to find it in row 6 of sheet Transfer (and from there you can get the column id) - see my answer bellow (untested)

Comment: I've looked at your sheet.  I get what you are doing - I think.  My first question would be why do you need to move the data that is in a column.  Why don't you just change the column dates?  I'm thinking that all the column dates could adjust themselves to be relative to the start date you enter.  This could easily be driven by formulas. Do I have a point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()

    Const WS_TR     As String = "Transfer"  'Sheet Transfer
    Const WS_RNG    As String = "H6:ABI6"   'row 6 on both sheets

    Dim wsSz As Worksheet, wsTr As Worksheet, cel As Range
    Dim found As Range, row6Sz As Range, row6Tr As Range

    Set wsSz = Sz001                'Code Name for the sheet "Sz001"
    Set wsTr = Worksheets(WS_TR)

    Set row6Sz = wsSz.Range(WS_RNG) 'searched values
    Set row6Tr = wsTr.Range(WS_RNG) 'search area

    For Each cel In row6Sz  'searched values

        Set found = row6Tr.Find(what:=Val(cel.Value2), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchFormat:=False, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)

        Debug.Print cel.Value2 & IIf(Not found Is Nothing, " Found", " Not Found")

    Next

End Sub
```

.

Note:

- I replaced the MsgBox with **Debug.Print**
- For results press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, or View -> Immediate Window

Comment: Thank you, I used the code but I am getting "Run-time error 13: Type mismatch." It highlight the "Set found" section from beginning to end. Any recommendations?

Comment: I tested it and the edited answer works - please try it now (open the Immediate Window in VBA)

Comment: We're close, it's working, but I am unsure of how to modify the code so it interacts with the sheet now. If I am reading the code correctly, if I disable the "Debug.Print" line it should instead pop up with message boxes saying "Found" or "Not Found". I tried this, but no message boxes are appearing. I will later need to replace the message boxes with code to retrieve the values underneath the found values from Transfer (Note: I'll make this portion a separate topic if I need any help with it, but recommendations are always welcome). Any thoughts?

Comment: Pop up messages will show only if you replace `Debug.Print` with `MsgBox` but **you'll get 731 popup boxes where you'll have to click Ok for each one to continue** (this is why I replaced it with the Debug.Print)

Comment: Ah, okay, now I see. Thank you so much, this is working as required, and is much faster than my original coding. I'll continue working on the remaining functions and post a new topic if I have any questions. Thank you again for your help!